# How to get information from Google Drive using Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

How to read data from Google Drive, such as file name, etc.?

I want to get the file name, the link and the picture of the first page of a book (if it's possible) in Google Drive using Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive has a REST API, check the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Specifically, there is a service to search files:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

In Android you can consume REST API using Retrofit:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/

It works perfectly with Kotlin.

Comment: is there any tutorial or something more specific for the only necessary steps to fix my issue please.

Comment: Problem with the rest api is that it doesn't support appdata folder. Which some of us need to migrate.